# cannot retrieve value from database for textbox while other field is fine

Tags: php, html, mysql

As you can see, all text box have value but did not appear, while the field that were not text box only can appear.. I've checked = "" (maybe symbols issue) but did not find anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx565.png)

`$id=$_GET['updateosaid'];`

`` $sql4="SELECT * FROM `agreement` WHERE `id`=$id"; $statement4=mysqli_query($con,$sql4); $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement4); ``

`$cnum=$row['cnum'];`
`$sc_num=$row['sc_num'];`
`$sn=$row['sn'];`
`$ck=$row['ck'];`
`$mac_a=$row['mac_a'];`
`$mosa_date=$row['mosa_date'];`
`$mosa_time=$row['mosa_time'];`
`$engene=$row['engene'];`
`$ctr=$row['ctr'];`

this is the code that will call the value:

````
        Contract Number:<br>
        <select class="drop" name="cnum" value ="<?php echo $cnum;?>" selected="selected">

        <?php
        include "config.php";
        //connect db
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `osa`";
        $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        //display in option
        
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        $code=$row['cnum'];
           $amount=$row['osa_num'];
            echo "<option value='$code'>".
                "$code".
            "</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
       </div>

        <div class="column">
        Support Case Number:<br>
        <input type="text" id="sc_num" class="bg size" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $sc_num;?>"><br><br>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
        Serial Number:<br>
        <input type="text" id="sn" class="bg size" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $sn;?>"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        Certificate Key:<br>
        <input type="text" id="ck" class="bg size" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $ck;?>"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        MAC Address:<br>
        <input type="text" id="mac_a" class="bg size" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $mac_a;?>"><br><br>
        </div>


        <div class="column">
        Date:<br>
        <input class="bg" type="date" name="mosa_date" value="<?php echo $mosa_date; ?>"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        Time:<br>
        <input class="bg" type="time" name="mosa_time" value="<?php echo $mosa_time; ?>"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        Assigned Engineer:<br>
        <input type="text" id="engene" class="bg size" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $engene;?>"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        Counter:<br>
        <input type="number" id="ctr" class="bg size" value="<?php echo $ctr;?>"><br><br>
        </div>```
````

Comment: make sure you are getting value from database using print_r($row); after select query

Comment: var_dump($row) inside while to check what you get from db

Answer (score 0):

Check the table SCHEMA "SELECT * FROM `agreement` WHERE `id`=$id";
if it is same as the key you echo for the text box value, check the spelling if they are the same.